# remove stage from included template in GitLab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two gitlab config files, X and Y. X has the all job defitions and stages array. I want to include X from Y and remove one of the stages, but I got error about one the jobs complained about its stage is not avaialable.

Here are config files,

template X

```
stages:
    - stage_a
    - stage_b

job_a:
    stage: stage_a

job_b:
    stage: stage_b
```

Template Y

```
include:
    project: ...
    file: X...

stages:
    - stage_a
```

I expect only job_a to run but I got following error
job_b: chosen stage does not exist; available stages are .pre, stage_a, .post

How can I remove a stage from included template?

Comment: If a job is defined in a stage I don't think you would be able to remove the stage itself. But if you're omitting that job, the related stage won't appear in your pipeline either unless there's any other job defined in the same stage. So pipeline-wise that shouldn't affect you, but on your YAML file you're stuck with that piece of config there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *remove* the stages, but you can override them. The rule is *closest scope wins*. In your case, Template Y is overriding the `stages:` keyword that is imported from Template X. This is problematic because `job_b` requires `stage_b` to exist because it defines `stage: stage_b`. **All stages defined in jobs must exist in `stages:`.**

To fix this issue, you can either make sure `stage_b` is included in `stages:` or change the `stage:` for `job_b` to be one of the stages you've defined in `stages:`.

```yaml
stages:
  - stage_a
  - stage_b

# OR
job_b:
  stage: stage_a
```

If you don't want the jobs in `stage_b` to run, simply not defining the stage does not work. You must use `rules:` or `only:`/`except:` or `when:` to prevent jobs from running.

```yaml
job_b:
  stage: stage_a  # ensure stage is valid
  rules: # disable this job
    - when: never
```

---

You could also avoid this problem altogether by not defining `stages:` in job templates (in accordance with [best practices](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html)) and [use inputs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/inputs.html) to define job stages in the template, so the template user can define the stages.

```
# template X

spec:
  inputs:
    stage_name_a:
      default: "stage_a"
    stage_name_b:
      default: "stage_b"

----

job_a:
  stage: $[[ inputs.stage_name_a ]]
  # ...

job_b:
  stage: $[[ inputs.stage_name_b ]]
  # ...
```

Then use it like:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy


include:
  - project: ...
    file: X...
    inputs:
      stage_a_name: build
      stage_b_name: deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be using rules. this might help you: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html

Another solution would be to restructure. My suggestion would be:

template X

```
stages:
    - stage_a
    - stage_b

job_a_template:
    script: ...

job_b_template:
    script: ...
```

Template Y

```
include:
    project: ...
    file: X...

job_a:
    extends:
        - "job_a_template"
    stage: stage_a
```